# Trying to make a slot machine bot with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

This is my code below:

```
import discord
import random
import time

tst = [1, 2, 3]

if "!roll" in message.content.lower():
    first = [await message.channel.send(str(random.choice(tst)).format(message))]
    time.sleep(1)
    second = [await message.channel.send(str(random.choice(tst)).format(message))]
    time.sleep(1)
    third = [await message.channel.send(str(random.choice(tst)).format(message))]
    time.sleep(1)
    if first == second == third:
        await message.channel.send("you win!".format(message))
```

The code works but doesn't send the message when you win.

I figured I am doing something wrong but can't figure out the correct way to write the code.

Comment: How's the code even working? `1st`, `2nd`, `3rd` are not valid variable names. (They start with a number)

Comment: i actually used another name for my code but changed it for the question. sorry

Comment: What ``if first == second == third:
               await message.channel.send("you win!".format(message)) ``is suppose to do ?

Comment: if the first, second and third results are the same from the randomization then i want it to send that message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never sends something because the if-statement is never true. You're comparing three lists of `discord.Message` instances for three messages. Those are all different, so `[message1] == [message2] == [message3]` will never be `True`. Compare the values instead.

Also, `.format(message)` doesn't do anything at all, and I'm not sure what you're expecting it to do. You should just remove it (or make it do something useful).

```py
first = random.choice(tst)
second = random.choice(tst)
third = random.choice(tst)

await message.channel.send(str(first))
await message.channel.send(str(second))
await message.channel.send(str(third))

if first == second == third:
    await message.channel.send("You win!")
```

Also,

> if "!roll" in message.content.lower():

Consider using `commands` instead of manually parsing everything. There's a basic example on how they work on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_bot.py).

Comment: thank you! im still new to coding so i didnt know why it didnt work

Comment: If this solves your issue you should mark my answer as correct.